# Load Bean from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, javabeans

I already searched a lot but can't find my error.
I have a servlet and try to put an ArrayList in a bean:

```
ClientBean c = new ClientBean();
c.setList(ClientsHandler.getAllClients());
request.setAttribute("listClients", c);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("showClients.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In the "showClients.jsp" i try to print the phone of the client 1:

```
<jsp:useBean id="listClients" class="beans.ClientBean" scope="request"/>
<% ArrayList<ClientsRowGateway> list = ((beans.ClientBean)request.getAttribute("listClients")).getList(); %>
<% out.println( ""+list.get(1).getPhone() ); %>
```

But i have a NullPointerException, because my object list is null.
How can i have access to a variable(getPhone()) inside of an object(Client) inside of an ArrayList inside of a bean???

After more tests, i try to access my ArrayList directly without a bean and works, print the client phone!

```
<%
ArrayList<ClientsRowGateway> testList = ClientsHandler.getAllClients();
if( testList != null )
    out.println( testList.get(1).getPhone() );
%>
```

But i need to use a bean, i just do this for a test, so can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure `ClientsHandler.getAllClients()` isn't returning null? Also, please do not use Scriptlets.

Comment: Yes, i already test and works fine. That isn't the problem.

Comment: Honestly that seems like the only explanation. Print out the value of `ClientsHandler.getAllClients()` and then check your implementation of `ClientBean#getList()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are loading the correct .jars. Usually for this kind of stuff you need some specific jars to run JSP's/servlets on the server.

Comment: Oh my God, a big simple and stupid resolution. I pass my project to my friend, and the reference of the .jars was of my computer adresses ^^

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the EL (Expression Language)?? to access the second item the sentence will be `${listClients.list[1].phone}`.

If you can't use EL, when you use the useBean tag you are already declaring an variable so you can access directly to the bean so.

```
<jsp:useBean id="listClients" class="beans.ClientBean" scope="request"/>
<% ArrayList<ClientsRowGateway> list = listClients.getList(); %>
<% out.println( ""+list.get(1).getPhone() ); %>
```

I suggest you to check if the getList method return correctly the list.

I hope this will help you

Comment: I already test with EL. I have the method getList() in the bean, but, i don't know why, doesn't work too. I decide to use Java code in the jsp Because i don't have experience with EL.

Comment: I try listClients.getList() directly too, but doesn't works :/
the method getList() was generated by eclipse, have no problem.

Comment: Let try to reply your classes to see if I have the same error.

Comment: Are you access to the servlet url ?? I reply your classes and your code and it work fine with the code I post.